# Why am I getting more Partitions after Partitioning based on a column that has 12 different values

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, partitioning

```
df = spark.read.format().load(path)

df.write.mode(WriteMode.Overwrite).format().partitionBy("ColumnX").save(path)
```

Note : ColumnX has 12 different values

```
df_partitioned = spark.read.format().load(path)

print(df_partitioned.rdd.getNumPartitions())

output: 80
```

Why am i getting 80 instead of 12

Comment: can you check how many physical files do you have?

Comment: If one partition has many rows and put it as one partition then it will slow down when you do something. So, the partitionBy will not create only one partition for each item.

Comment: Could you please check getNumPartitions() before using partitionBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spark, the word "partition" refers to memory partitions and disk partitions.  `df_partitioned` has 80 memory partitions and 12 disk partitions.  `repartition` and `coalesce` change the number of memory partitions as described [here](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4).  `partitionBy` changes the number of disk partitions as described [here](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/partitionby/).

Memory partitions and disk partitions are different but the terminology makes them sound the same, so you're understandably confused.

These will all write out a different number of files:

```scala
// approach 1
df
  .repartition(col("ColumnX"))
  .write
  .partitionBy("ColumnX")
  .parquet(outputPath)

// approach 2
df
  .repartition(5)
  .write
  .partitionBy("ColumnX")
  .parquet(outputPath)

// approach 3
df
  .repartition(8, col("ColumnX"), rand)
  .write
  .csv(outputPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading the data / datafram by default based on the default parlallism the rdd are getting partitioned. In case you want to ensure the number of partition to happen use repartition(n) when n is the number you want to provide.

df.repartition(10).write.mode(WriteMode.Overwrite).format().partitionBy("ColumnX").save(path)